# Is there any way to find all the JWT errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

How to find the list of each and every JsonWebToken(JWT) errors like error name and description. and how to handle all exceptions

```
TokenExpiredError = "Token has expired"
```

```
JsonWebTokenError = "Invalid token or signature"
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle JSON Web Token (JWT) errors and exceptions, you can use a library such as jsonwebtoken in Node.js. The library provides built-in error types for various JWT-related errors, including TokenExpiredError and JsonWebTokenError.

To find the list of error types and their descriptions, you can refer to the library's documentation. Here's an example of how you can handle JWT errors and exceptions using the jsonwebtoken library:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

try {
  // Verify and decode the JWT
  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);

  // Token is valid, continue with the application logic
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) {
    // Token has expired
    console.log('Token has expired');
  } else if (error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
    // Invalid token or signature
    console.log('Invalid token or signature');
  } else {
    // Other unexpected errors
    console.log('An error occurred:', error.message);
  }
}
```

In this example, the jwt.verify() function is used to verify and decode the JWT. If an error occurs during the verification process, the code checks the type of the error using instanceof to determine the specific JWT error type. Based on the error type, you can handle each error separately, such as logging an appropriate error message or taking any necessary actions.

Remember to replace token and secretKey with your actual JWT and secret key, respectively.

Note that different JWT libraries may have slightly different error types or methods to handle JWT errors. Make sure to consult the documentation specific to the JWT library you are using for a comprehensive list of error types and their descriptions.